# Can I get $size in mongo aggregation right away

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
Exercise.aggregate([
   {$match: {}},
   {
      $group: {
         _id: '$userId',
         correct: {$push: '$stats.correctWords'} // correctWords is array => ['a', 'b', 'c']
      }
   },
   {
      $addFields: {
          correctItems: {
             $reduce: {
                 input: '$correct',
                 initialValue: [],
                 in: { $setUnion: ['$$value', '$$this'] }
             }
          }
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
          correctsCount: {$size: {$ifNull: ['$correctItems', []]}},
      }
   }
])
```

some input:

```
{userId: 'a', stats: {correctWords: ['a', 'b'],  ...}}
{userId: 'b', stats: {correctWords: ['a', 'd'],  ...}}
{userId: 'a', stats: {correctWords: ['g', 'bc'], ...}}
{userId: 'b', stats: {correctWords: ['a', 'tt'], ...}}
```

need output:

```
[{userId: 'a', correctsCount: 4}, {userId: 'b', correctsCount: 3}]
```

$reduce returns an array of elements, can I somehow immediately calculate them without additional $project ?

Comment: I doubt that is possible to achieve the count within the same stage, unless you apply the same `$reduce` operator and the perform `$count` in another field which is redundant and not recommended.

Comment: Use `$addToSet` instead of `$push`

Comment: I cant, MyArrayFieldWithNestedItems is array field. I'm very sorry, I'm not strong in mongo and I'm confused and I've already confused everyone, let me post what I did and it works, I just think that my solution is terrible, sorry for my English

Comment: Please provide some sample input data, otherwise it will be difficult to provide any help.

Comment: I provide some input data, and expected result

Answer (score 2):

you can calculate the count of elements directly within the $addFields stage using the $size operator and the $reduce expression.

```
Exercise.aggregate([
   { $match: {} },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: '$userId',
         correct: { $push: '$stats.correctWords' }
      }
   },
   {
      $addFields: {
         correctsCount: {
            $size: {
               $reduce: {
                  input: '$correct',
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: { $setUnion: ['$$value', '$$this'] }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

By combining the $size operator and the $reduce expression within $addFields, you can calculate the count of elements without the need for an additional $project stage.

hope it's helpful..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `$reduce`. Simply use

```
{
   $set: { items: { $setUnion: "$myInputFromPreviousGroupAction" } }
}
```

You can also use `$size`

```
{
   $set: { items: { $size: { $setUnion: "$myInputFromPreviousGroupAction" } } }
}
```

Comment: I get an error. Maybe because after $group myInputFromPreviousGroupAction is an array of arrays. I will update my question

Comment: @Roma, that's exactly why a good question should include minimal data set sufficient to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, my mistake, I forgot to indicate that this is why reduce is used

Comment: This answer would work if $push was fed already unpacked data from arrayField, but I don't know how to do it.